# Jquery scroll to div if not visible and stop scrolling on user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the jquery code below to let the page smoothly scroll to a specific div if it is not currently visible on the screen:

```
if (!$('#list-panel').visible(true)) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#article-panel').offset().top - 150}, 4000);
}
```

This works fine as need. What I want is if the user while scrolling hits any key on the keyboard or the mouse, it should stop the scroll so the user can interact normally. Currently, the user has to wait until the scrolling is totally done. Please note that by default, I need it to scroll slowly and smoothly as you see the code within 4 seconds, but if the user decided not to wait and hit the keyboard or the mouse then the scroll should stop immediately.

Comment: @daliaessam : So you mean to say that, if you change scroll using this code, it takes lots of time and user have to wait till reaches to the place... right?

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan No, please read before commenting. I said it works fine on scrolling if not visible but I need it to stop scrolling if the user takes any action like hitting the keyboard or the mouse. and yes I need it by default to slowly scroll within 4 seconds.

Comment: @Parag Bhayani please read the full question, I do not see anything not clear.

Comment: @daliasessam: Okay question is clear now, need to clarify one thing still, if  your animation is reached halfway and if user clicks, then scrolling should be immidiately stop at the half way... right/

Comment: @Parag Bhayani Yes you are right. If the user takes any action while scrolling it should stop the scrolling immediately so the user can interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be registering an event when you start the animation, and later on unregister the event, so with the time it doesn't have too many registered events on your element

to stop animation you could use below code

```
$('html, body').stop();
```

On any specific event it becomes

```
$('html, body').on('click'), function() {
    $('html, body').stop();
}
```

but now you want to do this when only animation starts, and you need to call that event handler only once so it should be

```
function stopScroll () {
        $('html, body').stop();
}

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#article-panel').offset().top - 150}, {duration:5000}).one("click", stopScroll);
```

but also you want to deregister events after your code completes execution

```
function stopScroll () {
    $('html, body').stop();
}

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#article-panel').offset().top - 150}, {duration:5000, complete:function(){
    $('html, body').un("click", stopScroll);
}}).one("click", stopScroll);
```

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***

For handling multiple events, it's better to bind these events. For example, `click` starts animation and `keypress` stops it:

```
$('html, body').bind({
          'click' : function(){
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#d4').offset().top}, {duration:4000});
          },
          'keyup' : function(){
            $('html, body').stop();
          }

        });
```

For mobile, you can add tap, swipe, etc... using jQuery mobile (https://jquerymobile.com/)

**Code pen**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRworb

===

jQuery animate function has a *step* *callback* you could use to check user has clicked or pressed a key.

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated
>   element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween
>   object to change the value of the property before it is set.

**Info**: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I've made an example here:

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>
<div id="d4"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#d1, #d2, #d3, #d4 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#d1{
  background-color: red;
}

#d2{
  background-color: blue;
}

#d3{
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

#d4{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
if ( $('#d3').css('display') == 'none' ) {

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#d4').offset().top}, {duration:4000,
                           step : function(){
        $('html, body').on('click',function(e){
          $('html, body').stop();
        });
    }});
}
```

**CodePen**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBYoOj

Comment: Great, working with the mouse click. Can you please add events for mouse wheel, keyboard any button click, touches on mobile?

Comment: @stig-js : Dont know why you get upvote for this, but this is certainly not a good approach, step function is called many times during a transition and you are registering click events on it everytime ... so after a some time you might have click events registered hundreds of times ...

Comment: @ParagBhayani I've updated the answer, bind would be better for multiple events.

Comment: @stig-js What I want is on DOM ready, if the div is not visible , it automatically scroll to it but if the user takes any action like mouse or keyboard or touch while scrolling, the scrolling should stop immediately. So what implementation should be used.

Comment: you sould use the bind handlers